# Send Mail with link to current_user

Tags: shortcode, forms, email

I need a plugin which should send an mail to the "current_user" after a click on a "send" button.
The reason for this that I have some pdf.files which should not be downloadable directly. There is a short description of the Pdf with a "send" button. If the user click the button a "download link" should be sent to his login mail.

I have tried a lot of different form-plugins, but none of this accepts a shortcode in the "to" field.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gravity Forms will be your solution, but you will have to do some custom notifications.

You will also need User Registration Add-On the https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/

What you will need to do is:

1. Create a hidden field called for example "current user email" and allow it to be populated automatically.
2. Create a user registration feed and select Update User Option
3. Link this field with logged in user meta info - this will populate the form with current logged in user email address
4. Create a new notification template on submission and select option Email to -> Select a field -> Send To a Field -> Your hidden field. Screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/pHX5r4udu
5. Configure the rest of the email
6. Voilà it works

Comment: Thank you for your help and description, but  this is a very expensive solution $ 259 per year and, I don;t need all the other stuff. Maybe some lines of php code can do the same??. I already get the "current_user" with a simple funtion but than I stuck.

Comment: and I have no problem to pay some amount for a good solution :)

Comment: I have done a bit of Googleing and found this thread using contact form 7: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406149/dynamicly-populate-contact-form-7-input-fields-with-current-user-info-when-logge

Comment: Excellent, very helpful. I'v done also a lot of searching but found nothing like this.